# Clickhouse-copier SAXParseException: Syntax error in line 1 column 0

Tags: xml, clickhouse

I need to transfer some tables with data between two servers. I tried using clickhouse-copier, but I get SAXParseException: Syntax error in line 1 column 0. I don't know what's wrong with my task. I've add `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the beginning, but error in line 1 column 0 remain.

**Task.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<clickhouse>
    <remote_servers>
        <source_cluster>
            <shard>
                <internal_replication>false</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>server1_ip</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                </replica>
            </shard>
        </source_cluster>
        <destination_cluster>
            <shard>
                <internal_replication>false</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>server2_ip</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                </replica>
            </shard>
        </destination_cluster>
    </remote_servers>
    <max_workers>4</max_workers>
    <settings_pull>
        <readonly>1</readonly>
    </settings_pull>
    <settings_push>
        <readonly>0</readonly>
    </settings_push>
    <settings>
        <connect_timeout>3</connect_timeout>
        <insert_distributed_sync>1</insert_distributed_sync>
    </settings>

    <tables>
        <table1>
            <cluster_pull>source_cluster</cluster_pull>
            <database_pull>db_name</database_pull>
            <table_pull>table1</table_pull>

            <cluster_push>destination_cluster</cluster_push>
            <database_push>db_name</database_push>
            <table_push>table1</table_push>
            <engine>
                some_engine
            </engine>
            <sharding_key>jumpConsistentHash(intHash64(UserID), 2)</sharding_key>
        </table1>
        ...
    </tables>
</clickhouse>
```

**Error log:**

```
2022.10.04 17:00:46.568806 [ 4017 ] {} <Error> : virtual int DB::ClusterCopierApp::main(const std::vector<std::string> &): Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 0, SAXParseException: Syntax error in line 1 column 0, Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. ./build_docker/../contrib/poco/XML/src/XMLException.cpp:0: Poco::XML::SAXParseException::SAXParseException(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::XML::Locator const&) @ 0x15a6461e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
1. ./build_docker/../contrib/poco/XML/src/ParserEngine.cpp:0: Poco::XML::ParserEngine::handleError(int) @ 0x15a693e0 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
2. ? @ 0x15a6865c in /usr/bin/clickhouse
3. ./build_docker/../contrib/poco/XML/src/ParserEngine.cpp:249: Poco::XML::ParserEngine::parse(Poco::XML::InputSource*) @ 0x15a67c73 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
4. ./build_docker/../contrib/poco/XML/src/DOMBuilder.cpp:101: Poco::XML::DOMBuilder::parse(Poco::XML::InputSource*) @ 0x15a4d298 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
5. ./build_docker/../contrib/poco/XML/src/DOMParser.cpp:0: Poco::XML::DOMParser::parse(Poco::XML::InputSource*) @ 0x15a4c5e5 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
6. ./build_docker/../contrib/poco/Util/src/XMLConfiguration.cpp:0: Poco::Util::XMLConfiguration::load(Poco::XML::InputSource*, unsigned long) @ 0x15a3f789 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
7. ./build_docker/../contrib/poco/Util/src/XMLConfiguration.cpp:0: DB::getConfigurationFromXMLString(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) @ 0x7ab7075 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
8. ./build_docker/../programs/copier/ClusterCopier.cpp:244: DB::ClusterCopier::reloadTaskDescription() @ 0x7a55915 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
9. ./build_docker/../contrib/poco/Foundation/include/Poco/AutoPtr.h:231: DB::ClusterCopier::init() @ 0x7a5301c in /usr/bin/clickhouse
10. ./build_docker/../contrib/libcxx/include/__memory/shared_ptr.h:816: DB::ClusterCopierApp::mainImpl() @ 0x7a501b1 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
11. ./build_docker/../programs/copier/ClusterCopierApp.cpp:0: DB::ClusterCopierApp::main(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&) @ 0x7a50c5d in /usr/bin/clickhouse
12. ./build_docker/../contrib/poco/Util/src/Application.cpp:0: Poco::Util::Application::run() @ 0x15a244a2 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
13. ./build_docker/../programs/copier/ClusterCopierApp.cpp:0: mainEntryClickHouseClusterCopier(int, char**) @ 0x7a50f2e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
14. ./build_docker/../programs/main.cpp:0: main @ 0x78d8beb in /usr/bin/clickhouse
15. __libc_start_main @ 0x2409b in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so
16. _start @ 0x76b07ee in /usr/bin/clickhouse
 (version 22.10.1.400 (official build))
```

Comment: It simply means that XML is not valid and you missed a tag. Just use any online XML validator to check your full config ( without ... )

Comment: I have tried 5 different validators and they all say my xml is correct

Comment: try with more simple expression than `jumpConsistentHash(intHash64(UserID), 2)` (for a test)

Comment: What CH version? Old CH expected `<yandex>` as a root tag.

Comment: CH version is 22.10.1.400. I tried `rand()` instead of `jumpConsistentHash(intHash64(UserID), 2)`, but nothing changes. Still syntax error in line 1 column 0

Comment: maybe it's itf-8 BOM header in first 3 bytes without encoding, but i'm not sure

do you have non empty relative `conf.d` folder for your copier.xml config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my ZooKeeper server. After replacing it with ClickHouse Keeper, everything works fine.